Github Packages Documentation lacking for usage of owner repository dependencies
Github Packages documentation says that when using github hosted maven packages that you have to use the following url format:
repositories {
    maven {
        url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY")
        credentials {
            username = project.findProperty("gpr.user") ?: System.getenv("USERNAME")
            password = project.findProperty("gpr.key") ?: System.getenv("TOKEN")
        }
   }
}

When using multiple packages this creates a huge gradle file with a lot of repetition.
Instead you can use the following url format:
repositories {
    maven {
        url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/OWNER/*")
        credentials {
            username = project.findProperty("gpr.user") ?: System.getenv("USERNAME")
            password = project.findProperty("gpr.key") ?: System.getenv("TOKEN")
        }
   }
}

This way you only need 1 maven repository block instead of 40 in our case.
Source: https://medium.com/viascom/publishing-artefacts-to-github-packages-with-gradle-773928e95a58
I would have expected the documentation to include this.
So I leave this here.
